# Bootstrap accordion expand all

Tags: php, sql, bootstrap-4

I have created an accordion from my database table where each row is a new card, the first column is the heading by which it expands and the remaining columns are the content of the collapsible part.

This works perfectly as expected, but was wondering if there is a way to try get a button outside of this that will expand them all?

```
$i = '0';

$var = '<div id="accordion">';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stmt = DB::run($sql);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $col1 = $row['col1'];
    $col2 = $row['col2'];
    $col3 = $row['col3'];
    $col4 = $row['col4'];

    $i++;

    $var .= '<div class="card">';

        $var .= '<div class="card-header" id="heading'.$i.'">';
            $var .= '<button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse'.$i.'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse'.$i.'">';
                $var .= $col1;
            $var .= '</button>';
        $var .= '</div>';

        $var .= '<div id="collapse'.$i.'" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading'.$i.'" data-parent="#accordion">';
            $var .= '<div class="card-body">';
                $var .= $col2;
                $var .= $col3;
                $var .= $col4;
            $var .= '</div>';
        $var .= '</div>';

    $var .= '</div>';
}

$var .= '</div>';
```

Comment: if i understand you right , you are looking to create button with function to expand all cards?

Comment: @bobibobi yeah thats right

Comment: it can be done with jquery $.each function  https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: when 'Expand all' button is clicked you need to add 'show' class along with 'collapse'    to open all accoridon

Comment: Just adding a class is not enough, if you actually want to honor basic accessibility requirements. But your code looks like it is wrong in that regard to begin with, because you output `aria-expanded="true"` on every button, but none of the actual collapse elements is shown to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've added this: `$('.collapse').each(function(){$(this).addClass('show');}); to my new button. @misorude I'm new to bootstrap so just learning, changed that to false but what else should I be adding? P.S. so far this is just on the backend of my site so i'm not too concerned with accessibility at the moment to be honest

Comment: The ARIA attributes tell tools like screen readers and other assistive technology, which item(s) are currently “active”, so in an end-user facing scenario, those should be modified accordingly as well. But if this is just for your own custom backend, accessibility is probably not that big of a concern, that’s right.

Comment: @misorude thanks for the explanation, even though it is for my own back end might as well do it right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me in the end:

```
function expand_all(){
    $('.collapse').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('show');
    });
    $('.accordion-btn').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('aria-expanded','true');
    });
}
function collapse_all(){
    $('.collapse').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('show');
    });
    $('.accordion-btn').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('aria-expanded','false');
    });
}
```